# How to join returned data from different processes

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

What is the best way to collect data from all processes running in parallel. Getting the return value of a single process is not a problem, but how to aggregate them?

```python
class Controller(object):

    def get_square(self,a):
        return a*a

if __name__=="__main__":
    controller=Controller()
    jobs=[]
    for param in (10,20,30):
        process=Process(target=controller.get_square,kwargs={"a":param})
        jobs.append(process)
        process.start()
    for job in jobs:
        job.join()
    # printing result for all processes
```

Comment: use a `Queue` or a `Pipe`.  See [Exchanging objects between processes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes)

Comment: also in general you want your work units to be much larger than squaring a number :-)

Comment: sure thing, this was only an example ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def square(a, qOut):
    qOut.put(a**2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    qOut = Queue()
    params = (10, 20, 30)
    jobs = []
    for p in params:
        proc = Process(target=square, kwargs={'a':p, 'qOut':qOut})
        jobs.append(proc)
        proc.start()
    for job in jobs:
        job.join()
    for i in range(len(params)):
        print(qOut.get())
```